# LLVM: error: 'class llvm::Function' has no member named 'hasFnAttribute'

Tags: function, llvm

I'm trying to use the method function::hasFnAttribute,
but the result is:

```
error: 'class llvm::Function' has no member named 'hasFnAttribute'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
Module::iterator flti;
for(flti = Mod->begin(); flti != Mod->end(); flti++){

 Function * actual = flti;
 bool attr = actual->hasFnAttribute("inlinehint");
 //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the proper LLVM version - this method has only been added in version 3.3 (released on June 2013).